# You can't love your country only when you win

Tags: meaning

President Biden said in his State of the Union this year as follows:

"My predecessor and some of you here seek to bury the truth of January 6th.
I will not do that.
This is a moment to speak the truth and bury the lies.
And here’s the simplest truth. You can’t love your country only when you win."

What does he mean by saying "You can't love your country only when you win?"

Comment: I think questions about what politicians' words mean are pointless. All politicians *specialize* in weasel words and misdirection, *all the time*.

Answer (score 2):

The negative is understood as follows:

> You can't (love your country only when you win).

And there, "can't" is understood to mean "ought not (have the attitude)".  You can't have the view that the country is worthy of your love only when your party wins the election.

He was saying it to the party who claimed the election was "rigged" and "stolen" when they lost.

Comment: To put it politely, their actions also showed lack of love by show of ... anger.

Comment: And a love of falsehood.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental idea here is that a person's love of country should be independent of that person's personal benefit, advantage, or success.

In 1816, Stephen Decatur offered one of the most famous toasts in U.S. political history:

> Our country! In her intercourse with foreign nations, may she always be in the right; but our country, right or wrong.

This statement of patriotism expresses a level of commitment to one's country—what we generally mean when we speak of "loving one's country"—that endures despite adverse or ill-advised policy decisions that the government may make, and certainly despite setbacks that may occur in the individual's personal political fortunes.

In the same vein, "You can’t love your country only when you win" argues that making one's love of country contingent on the success of one's political party or of one's own political endeavors betrays a lack of such love—and so a lack of true patriotism.